# "Signals" from library using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2013

I know that Qt has signals, using them in the library, you can make the implementation of any application tasks. Does VS have any analogues? Or maybe C++ in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.Signals2 is a very good portable library that implements functionality similar to Qt signals and slots.

Here is the link to the library:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/signals2.html